# MySQL order by two columns and order results again

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

My table has two columns which I need to sort by:

```
content title
```

Only some rows have data in the `content` column but all have some in the `title` column. I need to sort these rows so that those with data in the `content` column are first. I can do this by:

```
ORDER BY content DESC, title ASC
```

However, those top rows returned because of their `content` column also need to be sorted alphabetically by their `title` (not by their content which I assume is happening).

Ideas? Thanks.

**Update:**

Should have noted that `title` is a VARCHAR and `content` is TEXT. So arbitary text. `content` column is empty if no content, not NULL.

So for example:

```
`title`     `content`
title a
title b      this has content
title c      so does this
title d
```

The order would be:

```
title c
title b
title a
title d
```

Comment: What do the rows that dont have "data" contain ? null ?

Comment: You will see **title** column sorted alphabetically if and if only **content** column as same data. If not, first preference any have goes to **content** column

Comment: Can you give an example of your data and then also what order you want it sorted it ... cause IM confused !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you need, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN content IS NULL THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END
  ,content,title
```

Comment: This resolved it, I just modified it slightly chaninging IS NULL to = '' and removed the extra content field. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY (content='') DESC, title ASC
```

or maybe

```
ORDER BY title ASC,(content='') DESC
```

so always in title order, but ones with content are first (when title is the same)

Answer (score 0):

How about checking if the `content` field is empty first?

```
ORDER BY if(content = '', 0, 1), content, title
```

This will put non-empty content rows first. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Edit: replace `content = ''` with `content IS null` if appropriate.